# Get latest value at server

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Google Firebase for a restaurant app. I've set persistence enabled to true. The local cache works well for most use-cases.

When the user clicks on the item, I always want to read the latest value in the database ignoring what's in local cache.

Right now, if the user has already seen the item, firebase returns the previous value and shortly after it returns the updated value from the database.

Couldn't find the relevant api to read the current value in the db ignoring the local cache in the docs.

PS: I don't want to turn off persistenceEnabled.

Thank in advance,

Answer (score 0):

There are a few tricks to doing this. One trick is to set the `keepSynced` flag to true on the database ref. This will cause the server to push changes in that ref to your Firebase client, whether or not you currently are listening for data at that ref. That way, that ref is always up to date with the server, as long as you have a connection. If you don't have a connection however, you'll still receive the latest value in the local cache, which is maybe not what you want.

To truly bypass the local cache, you can use Firebase's REST API and query the backend directly. This allows you to do most of the same things as the SDK allows, but directly over HTTPS. See [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/) docs for more info.